# CCSprite Fadeout with children

Tags: objective-c, ccsprite

I'm using a `CCSprite` with a few other `CCSprite` objects added as children, the other animations I'm using (scale and rotate) work great and the children are animated too. But when I'm using `CCFadeOut`, it only fades the parent.

I've read that fadeout doesn't apply to the children. Is there any way other than iterating over every child and calling the fadeout on each of them?

Comment: Yeah, since `FadeOut` actually changes the `opacity`, when this property is changed, the effects are not propagated to the children...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is rendered obsolete by [Gregory Johnson Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23737473/456434)

---

Well, I guess your choices are (Ranked from simplest to complex):

1) Just go into the `CCSprite` class in `cocos2d` library, and hack it. (<3 open source). (**not recommended**).

```
-(void) setOpacity:(GLubyte) anOpacity
{
opacity_ = anOpacity;

// special opacity for premultiplied textures
if( opacityModifyRGB_ )
    [self setColor: colorUnmodified_];

    [self updateColor];

    for (id<CCRGBAProtocol> child in children ) {
        // You should check if child responds to selector or conforms to CCRGBAProtocol.
        [child setOpacity:opacity];
    }
}
```

2) Same as the solution above, except subclass `CCSprite` to `MyCCSprite`, and inherit from it instead of `CCSprite`. Finally, override `setOpacity:` in the new class:

```
- (void) setOpacity:(GLubyte)opacity
{
    [super setOpacity:opacity];
    for(id<CCRGBAProtocol> child in children) {
        [child setOpacity:opacity];
    }
}
```

3) Run the `CCFade` action on the parent **and** the children by iterating them. (silly, if you ask me).

**IMPORTANT:** Just please, please, please keep in mind that `opacity`is a property of the `CCRGBAProtocol`. Not all `CCNode` classes have it. So, make sure you keep that in mind.

**References:**

1. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1252

Answer (score 9):

As of Cocos2d ver. 2.1, CCNodeRGBA has a "CascadeOpacity" BOOL property.  Set it to YES on the parent CCSprite to fade out the children nodes as well as the parent.