# How to make a CCSprite object fade with child

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Suppose I have a CCSprite object named sprite,and add a label to be its' child.While I find out if I call

```
sprite.opacity = 0;
[sprite runAction:[CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:5.0 opacity:255]];
```

the label won't be faded with sprite,instead it will appear immediately.It seems like opacity property can't be inherited from its' parent.So How should I do this if I want both sprite and its' children to fade simultaneously without having to runAction for both parent and children.

Comment: This question may already have an answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409697/ccsprite-fadeout-with-children

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `CCRenderTexture` to render you whole hierarchy of nodes and manipulate it like a single node.

With this solution you will avoid the issue of overlapping nodes causing a darker opacity if you propagate opacity to the children individually.

This technique is explained here: http://2sa-studio.blogspot.com/2013/01/fading-node-hierarchy-with.html